# UICollectionview inside UICollectionViewCell not scrolling smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `collectionView` and it has three cell.
In the last cell I have added a `collectionView` But when the scroll the main collectionview the collectionview inside the cell is not scrolling.
If I don't scroll the main `CollectionView` it's working fine.

Here the it is working fine...

[image]

But when I scroll the main `collectionview` the Gallery `collectionview` does not scroll.

[image]

I have taken the `collectionview` inside a cell of the main `collectionView`